# ASP.net site works on dev machine but not on IIS - DB connection

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.net site that works just fine in dev environment, but does not produce an output when deployed to IIS. The site has a timer and updatepanel with a label. On every tick of the timer the code fetches a value from a SQL DB that is hosted on the same machine as the IIS server.

Here is the code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    protected void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "Data Source = LEWBWPDEV\\COMPLIANCE; Initial Catalog = 3CXCallStats; Integrated Security = True; Max Pool Size = 500";
        string select = "SELECT * FROM callsCounter WHERE ID = '1'";
        string count = "";
        SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand selectCMD = new SqlCommand(select, myCon);
        SqlDataReader myReader;

        myCon.Open();
        myReader = selectCMD.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            count = myReader["Counter"].ToString();
        }

        lblCounter.Text = count;
    }
```

Would I need to alter my Data Source? I've tried (local), localhost and 127.0.0.1.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Go to event viewer of that DEV machine and see what error it is throwing.  You should have implemented exception handling to troubleshoot easily.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any error. The page runs but no output is given. I'm going to add exception handling now to check for errors.

Comment: is your dev machine "LEWBWPDEV"?  I'm assuming "Deployed to IIS" means on a separate server - does that server have permissions for the database using integrated security?  That would usually mean different credentials are used in between your local and your deployed.

Comment: Check your application pool. You'll find more here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2015/04/14/how-to-add-the-applicationpoolidentity-to-a-sql-server-login/

Comment: LEWBWPDEV is my deployment box with IIS on it. It's already hosting a website that functions normally. I've tried re-adding IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool to the logins for the SQL server but no luck.

Comment: Integrated Security=SSPI instead of true?  However, something else may be up.  Double check the database table, isn't empty is it?  If there was an exception you'd get it shown in the web browser, providing nowhere else was catching it.  There could be lots of things wrong, not just the database connection and equally it could be behaving itself just fine!